# What is un-hold process?

Tags: discussion, moderation

I see a new user who's got a gem of an idea that just isn't articulated well for a SE-type question.  The question goes on hold.  My fear is that more often than not, that person is just going to go away in a huff. I fear it's even more likely if they do in fact make (what to them seems) a significant change, and there's no immediate release from Question Jail.

Someone who's been around the block a few times can see how to get a question in under the wire here, and may have "edit powers". The problem I have is I'm less willing to invest the effort if my editing, too, were going to languish around as long as the new user's first edit attempts typically do.

Q: What is the un-hold process?  Does it take a mod-majority vote, or does editing release a question automatically?

Comment: It's explained in the [help center](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions).

Answer (score 4):

If and when a question becomes a good fit, a moderator can open it immediately, or any person with 3,000 or more reputation points can [vote to reopen](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) it. I assume it takes five votes to reopen, just as it does to close, though I am uncertain of that. Those of us with less than 3,000 rep could post a link in chat or on meta to give the post attention.

There is a [review queue](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/review/) for reopen votes to ensure quality posts become visible.

Answer (score 4):

"on hold" works just like "closed" did before the wording change.

- 5 close votes or 1 moderator vote are required to close a question ("place on hold" now).
- 5 reopen votes or 1 moderator vote are required to reopen a closed question

There are review queues that people with 3000 reputation can visit to find questions with close and reopen votes.

So what does a user with <3000 reputation to do?

If a question needs to be closed please flag it with the "it doesn't belong here or is a duplicate" reason. When you cast this flag you automatically kick a post to the close vote review queue. You can also throw the link into the chat room, usually there is at least one mod there and several potential close voters.

The same is roughly true with reopening, though there is no autoflag to kick it to the queue (which actually I might just feature request). In this case the chat room and a custom flag to a moderator are a good bet.

Overall, if you see a question that was closed and the issues are addressed, please say something. If a question is mod closed you can ping the mod who closed it in the comments (even if they haven't said anything).

Comment: I second the idea of adding a feature request for an autoflag to add a post to the reopen queue. Such a feature may or not be useful on other SE sites, but it certainly seems like it would be valuable on C.SE.

Comment: @PhilipSchaff it's been suggested: Shog outlines reasons why this is a bad idea, and what a low rep user *can already do* to put a question into the reopen queue: [Can we have the ability to flag for reopening?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/186728). Mainly editing a closed question.